# python script that iterates over an item every minute

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dummy script that executes every minute. It will be a test script so am agnostic about the function. All I want to achieve is for the script to execute some function for the first 4 iterations and then fail on the 5th.

For each iteration, I want to pass the result to a separate log file that will contain the name of the script, operation (run, fail), timestamp. Let's call the script *task*.

Again, the code itself can be replaced. As long as the script executes some function the first four iterations and fails on the fifth. For the dummy function below, each item in `b` is subtracted by 5 every minute. This should be executed for the first 4 iterations until we hit  the value `x`, which should throw an error and stop working.

The script should not reset until error has been rectified.

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

a = 5
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'x']

timestamp = []

entry = []

for x in range(0, 5):  
    try:
        # msg.send()
        for num in b:
            if a - num == 3:
                entry.append("executed")
                timestamp.append(datetime.datetime.now())
            elif a - num != 3:
                entry.append("executed")
                timestamp.append(datetime.datetime.now())
            else:
                raise ValueError
        str_error = None
    except Exception as str_error:
        pass

    if str_error:
        sleep(60)  
    else:
        break

script = ['task.py','task.py','task.py']

data = [(script), (entry), (timestamp)]

columns = ['Script', 'Operation', 'Timestamp']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
```

intended output:

```
                    Script  Operation             Timestamp
0                     task   executed   2010-03-20 09:27:00
1                     task   executed   2010-03-20 09:28:00
2                     task   executed   2010-03-20 09:29:00
3                     task   executed   2010-03-20 09:30:00
4                     task     failed   2010-03-20 09:31:00
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask. Does the script you provide not do what you ask (though does it really need to be this ugly? The bare `except: pass` in particular)?

Comment: `str_error` is `None` so the `sleep` never happens; is that what you need help with?

Comment: The script can be cut. All I want to do is run a function successfully every minute for four consecutive times and then manufacture an error on the 5th sequence

Comment: Then that's `def call_me (): yield; yield; yield; yield; raise SomeError()`